# Can't do simple opacity transition on div

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

The opacity is not changing nor is it transitioning, any idea what I'm doing wrong?
(chrome browser)

I only want to set opacity to 0 if I'm adding the 'transitions' class. Such that it fades in, but does not fade out first.

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/t37k3/9/

```
<div></div>

<a href="#" class="start">start</a>


div { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

div.transitions {
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, -moz-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, -o-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s; 
}

$(".start").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").css('opacity', 0).addClass('transitions').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

edit: I forgot the class on the anchor, and am using inline opacity in real life.

Update: this is my solution I went with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16848785/33522

Comment: See my solution below... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848785/33522

Answer (score 1):

your selector in the fiddle isnt matching any elements

```
<a href="#" class="start">start</a>
```

$(".start") will match any element with a class "start"

http://jsfiddle.net/t37k3/5/

**Update**:

http://jsfiddle.net/t37k3/43/

in css add:

```
.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

js code:

```
$(".show").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").css('opacity', 0)  // sets the opacity to 0
    .addClass("notransition")   // add notransition class (will override any other transitions
    .addClass("transitions");   // add the transition css rules (notransition overrides)

    // need this in a setTimeout in order for the 
    // code to delay and let the jquery chaining finish 
    // before we remove notransition and set opacity to 1
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("div").removeClass("notransition")
       .css('opacity', 1)
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: you are chaining another .css call to set the opacity to 1 immediately, instead of letting the transition handle it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/t37k3/32/

Comment: mostly just fooling around before i actually figured out what your question was. :p

Comment: Sorry, my original question was not very clear. I've updated it w/ a solution. The trick was the setTimeout so my starting state could be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t37k3/20/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<a href="#" class="start">start</a> <!-- ADD A CLASS -->
```

CSS:

```
div { 
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

.transitions {
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;     /* NO NEED TO TRANSFORM */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s; 
    opacity:1;
}
```

jQ:

```
$(".start").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").addClass('transitions');
});
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for me. And why would switching to 'all' change anything when all I want is the opacity?

Answer (score 0):

To add to PSL's answer...

If you are adding the class to do the transition, put the end result css rules you want in the class that you are adding to the element.

So your .transitions class would look like this.

```
div.transitions {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, -moz-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, -o-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s; 
}
```

And your click would contain only

```
$(".start").addClass('transition')
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I only want to set opacity to 0 if I'm adding the 'transitions' class. Such that it fades in, but does not fade out. Doing what you suggest actually makes it fade out for me. http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/t37k3/26/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/t37k3/42/

```
<div></div>

<a href="#" class="start">start</a>

$(".start").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var transitions = true
        , $div = $("div"); 

    $div.removeClass('transitions');

    if ( transitions ) {
        $div.addClass('start');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $div.addClass('transitions').removeClass('start');
        }, 20);
    }
});

div { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

div.start {
    opacity: 0.1;
}

div.transitions {
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is what I ended up doing. I add a `.start` class to set the default state if we're using transitions. Then I add the `.transitions` class after a brief pause so the `.start` state will take effect.

Then I reset it on subsequent clicks (not necessary, but helps with fiddle demo).

Comments are welcome. I wanted to avoid doing any inline css in javascript if at all possible.